# Error: 'MDCMinimumOS.h' file not found materialcomponents

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components-ios

Unable to compile / archive using materialcomponents in XCode 13.3.1. Pod file is below,

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def sharedpods
   pod 'MaterialComponents', :git => 'https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios', :branch => ENV['DEFAULT_BRANCH']
   pod 'MDFInternationalization'

end
```

Error: 'MDCMinimumOS.h' file not found while archiving.